# Is there a way to shorten boolean RequestParams in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Thanks for all trying to help :)

Backround information:
I use the spring framework version 2.4.3 together with Java (and Maven)

To my question:
Is it possible to shorten `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/example?admin=true&superPrivilege=true` to something like `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/example?admin&superPrivilege`.

So what I want is to use boolean Parameters as Flag.
If the parameter is set then it counts as true if not as False. Is that possible in Spring Boot?

I actually don't know what to google for because I'm new with any kind of Webdevelopement.
(And jep I did try a couple of hours in the last days xD)

Comment: It would be faster to just try it, rather than asking here, no?

Comment: @JimGarrison As stated below I did goole a LOT and of course tried it too but didn't come to a working conclusion. That's why I'm coming here to get help. I only come here when I am so stuck that I can't get further by myself lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be:

```java
@GetMapping("/demo")
public String demo(@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
    if (parameters.containsKey("key")) {
        System.out.println("I has key");
    }
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: This solved it. I knew this existed but searched for an alternative, but yeah works quite fine :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the parameter is present or not in your url ,with `Optional<>`

```
 @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?>dataGet(@RequestParam("admin") Optional<Boolean> admin) {
        if(admin.isEmpty()) {
                  // Do anything //without admin role
            
        }
         else{
                // Do anything with admin role
                  }
}
```

Also if you are passing the parameter ,without any value it will be empty so you can check accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so I tried using the admin Parameter with Optional<Boolean> exactly like you above, but isPresent is false until I actually pass a boolean value to it

Comment: Updated it @DragonCoder added `Logical not (!)` operator ,it will solve the issue

Comment: Tried that too but now it is true even if I don't set the flag.
What I want is that no parameter means false and adding the flag ?admin making the bool true

Comment: I debugged and noticed that Optional is Optional.empty if I don't add the Parameter or pass no value to it. It changes to Optional[true]/Optional[false] if pass a value to the parameter

Comment: yeah you can use `isEmpty()` for the purpose ,updated the answer

Comment: thanks for trying to hel :) But the problem is, that I have to differenciate the two Optional.Empty values. So this approach doesn't work. I need to make a difference between passing now Parameter or passing one(without value)

Comment: umm ,okk .The accepted answer is a far better approach